# “Could not find a CFBundlePackageType” within the Info.plist using Application Loader

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

So im trying to upload an App for Mac OS X to the App Store using Application Loader. When I open Application Loader (version 3.5), I double click on "Deliver App", select MyApp.pkg and the following message appears:

"Could not find a CFBundlePackageType within the Info.plist; or the package is missing an Info.plist."

I´ve already searched for this error in Apple Forums and other posts in here and other forums and still can´t get it right. I checked the Info.plist in the contents of MyApp but, I think, everything is alright.

Info.plist:

```
<?xml version=“1.0.0” encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.0.dtd">
<plist version=“1.0.0”>
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Nimbo X</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>Nimbo X</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>electron.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.ecaresoftinc.nimbox</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Nimbo X</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>14D125</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.10</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>0640</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>6E35b</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string>public.app-category.developer-tools</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.9.0</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>AtomApplication</string>
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Encountered the same error message today.